# The idea of field norm

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Why is the field norm defined the way it is? What is the intuition and motivation behind its definition (as given in Wikipedia)? In other words, what's the essential idea of a field norm?

Comment: Try showing an element of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a unit if and only if it has norm 1. This was how I got my intuition for a field norm

Comment: To extend @SheelStueber’s remark, let me point out what happens when you take the reciprocal of any quadratic irrationality $m+n\sqrt d$. I hope you did this computation in high-school, and I recommend that you do a few more with specific integers for $m$, $n$, and $d$.